# How to add a line break in a woocommerce hook that has the purpose to translate a text string

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using the translate trick to translate text strings on woocommerce pages.
In this example I'm changing "quick view" when hovering over a product on the product catalog page into "Click For More Details".

How can I add a line break between "For" and "More" to achieve:

Click For 
More Details

This is the code I'm using, added into functions.php

```
//shop catalog page: rename quick view to More Details when hovering over product
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Quick View' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Click For More Details', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```

The relevant passage is

```
$translated_text = __( 'Click For More Details', 'woocommerce' );
```

I tried `"Click For" \n "More Details", 'woocommerce'` 
but that gave me an error

Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you tried `"Click For\nMore Details", 'woocommerce'`

Comment: yes, but it didn't work

Comment: You can try the following Click For <br>  More Details

Comment: I'm in a php file, so the output will be "Click For <br> More Details" ... that's the problem...